# How do I count cells that are not blank in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I'm stuck with a bug where I can't get my CountIf to work. In my "2020 Master RMA's" sheet, I have column A that has dates in it in the form of m/d/yyyy. What I want to happen is the following: Check Column A. If column A meets the January critera (ie, if the monthNum = 1), then go to directly over to column O and see if there is a date in that cell also. If there is a date in that cell , count that date along with the rest of the non-blank cells with dates in this column O.

I want the results of column O to go into a cell in another sheet called "March Presentations". The result will go in cell AE49.

I should be getting a value of 3 in cell AE49, but I am only getting a value of 1, and I still can't figure out why after a couple of hours of looking at this.

```
Sheets("2020 Master RMA's").Select
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For row = 2 To lastRow
    monthNum = Month(Worksheets("2020 Master RMA's").Range("A" & row).Value)
    If monthNum = 1 Then
        January = January + 1
        JanuaryQE = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("2020 Master RMA's").Range("O" & row), "<>""")
 Next

Sheets("March Presentation").Select
Worksheets("March Presentation").Range("AD49").Value = January
Worksheets("March Presentation").Range("AE49").Value = JanuaryQE
```

Comment: `JanuaryQE = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("2020 Master RMA's").Range("O" & row), "<>""")` - this stores the result of the countifs for one row only, namely the last row. Change the range to include all the rows and move the countifs outside the loop.

Comment: Just for clarification on the range part, when you say "Change the range to include all the rows", do you mean to go from .Range("O" & row) to just .Range("O")?

Comment: `JanuaryQE = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("2020 Master RMA's").Range("O2:O" & lastrow), "<>""")` and move it outside the loop.

Comment: Hmm, I am still getting a value of 1 when I pasted your line outside of the loop. Also, I want this CountIf to be applied only if the condition in column A is met (again, only if the condition for month = 1 is met). Wouldn't placing JanuaryQE outside of the loop affect that condition?

Comment: Then you need another criterion for the COUNTIFS.

Comment: Dang, I'd like it all to be in the For Loop if possible. So I'd essentially need another For Loop outside of this For Loop?

Comment: No. Highly suggest that you write the COUNTIFS in a cell on the worksheet, and when you've got it to your liking, translating it to VBA. From what I understand of your description, you don't need a loop at all. Actually I'd use SUMPRODUCT for this.

Comment: `JanuaryQE = JanuaryQE + IIF(Worksheets("2020 Master RMA's").Range("O" & row)<>"" and Worksheets("2020 Master RMA's").Range("A" & row) = 1, 1,0)`

Comment: @ScottCraner - I think you actually read the question more thoroughly than I did, haha... though I still would do this formulaically and ditch the loop.

Comment: @ScottCraner, is your line supposed to be added outside of the For loop? I tried it both in the For loop and out of the For loop, but now am getting a value of 0...

Comment: It goes in the loop, and it will only count where Column A is `1` AND Column O is not blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
With Worksheets("2020 Master RMA's")
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Row = 2 To lastRow
        monthNum = Month(.Range("A" & Row).Value)
        If monthNum = 1 Then
            January = January + 1
            januaryqe = januaryqe + IIf(.Range("O" & Row) <> "", 1, 0)
        End If
     Next
End With
With Worksheets("March Presentation")
    .Range("AD49").Value = January
    .Range("AE49").Value = januaryqe
End With
```

Comment: this is awesome! 

The only thing is is that I tried it for January and February and both of those worked, but March is actually giving me +1 more than I need in MarchQE...I'm trying to figure out why that is...

Comment: @user10550177 - you can do this directly with formulas, is there any reason you're using VBA?

Comment: @BigBen yeah that's true...I was building a button that did a few other things (the code that I pasted was just a snippet of some other things it was doing). I think I just wanted to try and keep it all in VBA if possible. But I could try that formula route too.